# How to get most repetitive data from a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an Emp table with duplicate values

```
    Emp Table               Expected Output
Id  JoiningDate Dept        Id  JoiningDate Dept
AA  2019-11-16  X1          AA  2019-11-16  X1
AA  2019-11-16  X1          BB  2017-05-12  X1
AA  2019-11-18  X1          CC  2011-05-20  X1
AA  2019-11-11  X1              
AA  2019-11-11  X1              
BB  2017-05-12  X1              
BB  2017-05-12  X1              
BB  2017-03-11  X1              
BB  2017-11-30  YYY1                
CC  2011-05-20  X1              
CC  2010-05-27  X1
```

1. If there are repetitive coulmns- get the highest date repetitive record
2. if there are multiple records, get the highest date record

My Query:

```
SELECT Id, Dept,  MAX(JoiningDate)
FROM Emp where Source = 'X1'
GROUP BY Id, Dept;
```

I am not sure how to get most-often values.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Why does `BB` have a value of `2017-11-30`? There is no row with that date for Dept `XX`. Is that intentional?

Comment: sorry, My Bad. I should be very careful before posting

Comment: There is no row with `2017-11-11` in your data; where does that value come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you need to do here is first get a windowed `COUNT` for each ID and Date (for when `Dept` has a value of `'X1'`). Then you can get a "TOP 1 in each group"; I use the `TOP (1) WITH TIES` method here to avoid a 2nd CTE:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES('AA',CONVERT(date,'2019-11-16'),'X1       '),
            ('AA',CONVERT(date,'2019-11-16'),'X1       '),
            ('AA',CONVERT(date,'2019-11-18'),'X1       '),
            ('AA',CONVERT(date,'2019-11-11'),'X1              '),
            ('AA',CONVERT(date,'2019-11-11'),'X1              '),
            ('BB',CONVERT(date,'2017-05-12'),'X1              '),
            ('BB',CONVERT(date,'2017-05-12'),'X1              '),
            ('BB',CONVERT(date,'2017-03-11'),'X1              '),
            ('BB',CONVERT(date,'2017-11-30'),'YYY1                '),
            ('CC',CONVERT(date,'2011-05-20'),'X1              '),
            ('CC',CONVERT(date,'2010-05-27'),'X1  '))V(Id,JoiningDate,Dept);
GO

WITH Counts AS(
    SELECT Id,
           JoiningDate,
           Dept,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Id, JoiningDate) AS Count
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE Dept = 'X1')
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       Id,
       JoiningDate,
       Dept
FROM Counts
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Count DESC, JoiningDate DESC);
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT count(Id), Id, JoiningDate, Dept
FROM Emp
GROUP BY Id, JoiningDate, Dept
ORDER BY count(Id), JoiningDate
```

Comment: None of these attempts return the value(s) the OP are after: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NJjCUcrd) Also, a good answer *explains* the solution; code only answers can be poorly received (that or the fact this is incorrect could be the reason for the downvote here).